# Php includes and folders

Tags: php, include

I’m creating a new site and in order to have the same navigation and footer in each page I created a footer and navigation files .

I put footer.php and navigation.php inside folder /include

this it the structure of my site so far:

**old site folder**

```
index.html  
other.html
```

**New Site folder**

```
/index.php
/biography.php
/style folder (style.css, responsive.css)
/images folder
/include folder (footer.php , navigation.php)
/media folder (videos.php)
```

the problems I have are with images included in footer and links within the navigation menu

for instance, on file biography.php I put on the footer area  this calls the footer just fine but the images I have in the footer are broken (the images reside in the images folder)
the same for navigation on biography.php, I have  but the links in nav menu go back to old site folder, for instance index.php links to oldsite/index.php instead of newsite/index.php

the file videos.php footer and navigation display all ok , images and links

I guess the issue is with the paths, I tried adding / and dots but it doesn’t work

I don’t know what to do..  :(

Answer (score 0):

you can include from your /include/footer.php with

```
dirname(__FILE__).'/images/filetoinclude'
```

Edit:

If you want to display images that are served by your webserver, you will have to specify either absolute path /images/images.jpg or the fully qualified path including its host as suggested above

Answer (score 0):

You can define definite path to your images:

for example:

```
<img src='<?="$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']"."/images/footer.png"?>' />
```

Comment: where would I have to put this ??

Comment: In your footer.php file,  and remember if you want to use it inside php tags you should use it like this:echo "<img src='".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/images/footer-logo.gif' />";

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can solve by `HTML`.

You must use absolute path in image source.

```
<img src="/images/footer.png" />
```

When you use slash in first of `src`, that mean start path from root of site.

Comment: the path of the images in my footer.php is src="../images/footer-logo2.gif” if I Ieave it with only one slash and no dots then the image is broken

Comment: HTML src of image tag work by url. For example your url is this: example.com/mypage. When you use slash in start of src, it src start path from root of domain.